# Unexpected issue while building examples for movidius neural compute stick (ncsdk)

Tags: linux, ncsdk

Recently I bought Movidius Neural Compute Stick and I started with provided tutorial on the website. **Make install** works without any issue. However, despite following exact steps I'm constantly failing into same error while running **make examples**:

```
mvNCCompile -w bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel -s 12 deploy.prototxt
mvNCCompile v02.00, Copyright @ Movidius Ltd 2016

Failed to include caffe_pb2, things might go wrong!
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/mvNCCompile", line 118, in 
create_graph(args.network, args.inputnode, args.outputnode, args.outfile, args.nshaves, args.inputsize, args.weights)
File "/usr/local/bin/mvNCCompile", line 100, in create_graph
from Controllers.CaffeParser import parse_caffe
File "/usr/local/bin/ncsdk/Controllers/CaffeParser.py", line 29, in 
import caffe
File "/opt/movidius/caffe/python/caffe/init.py", line 4, in 
from .proto.caffe_pb2 import TRAIN, TEST
File "/opt/movidius/caffe/python/caffe/proto/caffe_pb2.py", line 17, in 
serialized_pb='\n\x0b\x63\x61\x66\x66\x65.proto\x12\x05\x63(...most likely not important here...)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py", line 829, in new
return _message.default_pool.AddSerializedFile(serialized_pb)
TypeError: expected bytes, str found
Makefile:80: recipe for target 'compile' failed
make[4]: *** [compile] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/sebastian/Development/movidius_workspace/ncsdk/examples/caffe/GoogLeNet'
cp: cannot stat '../../caffe/GoogLeNet/graph': No such file or directory
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'googlenet' failed
make[3]: *** [googlenet] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/sebastian/Development/movidius_workspace/ncsdk/examples/apps/multistick_cpp'
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'multistick_cpp/.' failed
make[2]: *** [multistick_cpp/.] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sebastian/Development/movidius_workspace/ncsdk/examples/apps'
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'apps/.' failed
make[1]: *** [apps/.] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sebastian/Development/movidius_workspace/ncsdk/examples'
Makefile:51: recipe for target 'examples' failed
make: *** [examples] Error 2
```

My configuration is as follows:

```
sebastian@linux:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
sebastian@linux:~$ echo $PYTHONPATH
:/opt/movidius/caffe/python
sebastian@linux:~$ lscpu | grep "Model name"
Model name: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N2840 @ 2.16GHz
sebastian@linux:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial
```

I'd appreciate suggestions what I need to do to succesfully build examples.

Comment: @shellter This directory exists in the tree. Note that this is pointing to non-existent graph file. Which is not created because of earlier error.

Comment: Oops, didn't read that close enough. I don't see how I can help on this one except to wonder about the `TypeError` message. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

We did not find any issues during installation. Our configuration is as follows:

```
movidius@osboxes:~$ python --version
```

> Python 2.7.12

```
movidius@osboxes:~$ echo $PYTHONPATH
```

> :/opt/movidius/caffe/python

```
movidius@osboxes:~$ lscpu | grep "Model name"
```

> Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5300U CPU @ 2.30GHz

```
movidius@osboxes:~$ lsb_release -a
```

> No LSB modules are available.
>   Distributor ID: Ubuntu
>   Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
>   Release:    16.04
>   Codename:   xenial

Could you please run the `make clean` command and try again installation using `make install` then do `make examples`.

If you are still facing any issues please refer to the following links:

1. https://developer.movidius.com/start
2. https://movidius.github.io/ncsdk/install.html